# Change indentation bracket style on Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

#### Visual Studio Code Version: 1.32.3

I would like to change code indentation style on Visual Studio Code from this :

```
if (xRatio < yRatio)
{
  ...
}
```

to this :

```
if (xRatio < yRatio) {
  ...
}
```

Cannot find anything on Settings > Text Editor > Formatting ...

Any idea ? Should i use a plugin for this ?

### Edit

It **concerns all codes technos with brackets** (C++, JS, Java, etc ...)

Comment: You haven't said what language (C, C++, C#, Javascript, etc)... but I'm not aware of any options in VS for this. I've never used it but I'm aware of [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) which I think might do it

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is not actually "indenting",  but "beautifying".

For that there are specific plugins depending on the language that you want to beautify, and they have their own configuration.

For example, the beautify plugin for javascript that I use ( https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify ) has that kind of formatting as the default.

I'd say that in most plugins that is actually the default, but I'm not 100% sure.